# Find Currency Symbol in Currency Data C#

Tags: c#

I want to find which Currency Symbol exists in Currency Format data.

For example, Input String = $56.23

```
public class FormatConverter 
{
    private CultureInfo _cultureInfo;

    public void UpdateCultureInfo()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
        var thread = new Thread(
            s => _cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);

        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
    }

    Bool TryParseCurrencySymbolAndValue(string input, out string CurrencySymbol,
                                        out double value)
    {
        if(_cultureInfo == null)
            UpdateCultureInfo();
        try{

        // Convert Currency data into double
        value = Double.Parse(input, NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol);
        // How to extract Currency Symbol?
            CurrencySymbol = "$";
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex){ /* Exception Handling */}
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want to extract "$" symbol from a string and 56.23 separately and then I want to apply CultureInfo to 56.23 into French Format. The output should be $56,23.

In some cases, input might be "Euro sign" or some other currency symbol in the beginning or in the end of input string.

I know how to convert into CurrentCulture for Numeric part. I don't know how to extract currency Symbol from a string.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand something, but isn't the currency symbol always the first character in the string, and isn't it always one character long? That is, couldn't you do char currency = money[0]? And then string amount = money.Substring(1)?

Comment: In some european format, it might at the end like 200,00 <Euro Symbol> or Rs. 200.00 Indian Format

Comment: the question is will the format always have the $ as the first char..? is so use IndexOf Method or always look for the $ character in the zero index position [0]

Comment: From what I understood, Euro is written like this: €890.. Again, first character. If the currency "symbol" is the actual word, then you have to type in all the possible currencies that might be entered and then identify them in the string with String.IndexOf

Comment: If you look at the Currency Symbol of Hong Kong(HK$) or Taiwan(NT$), in this case it will incorrect. Is there any Windows API or string formatting class to get Currency Symbol in a particular string.

Comment: @Daniel, Euro symbol is always written after the amount and the same applies to many other currencies - Czech crown for instance.. Czechs currency sign consists of more letters, usually written as Kč or Czk. You can't rely on currency sign to be a one letter symbol, nor to be written always before the amount.

Comment: @walther I provided more alternatives in my answer.. And also, in the Wikipedia article, all values are written with the Euro symbol before the amount..

Comment: sounds like he needs to have an array of all Currency Symbols..

Comment: Actually, according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_sign#Usage, the use of the Euro symbol can vary wildly.. In fact, it can also appear in the middle of the string, instead of a decimal point. If you want to truly account for every currency and every representation of the currency, then you're going to have to deal with a *lot* of edge cases.

Comment: @Daniel, not sure what background you're coming from, I'd guess US, but I'm using Euro every day and I can assure you, 99% it's written after the amount. Wikipedia can say anything,but the actual usage is a different thing. Never saw anyone to write 3€50 for instance. Sure, some people like to write it before the amount, but... Search for pretty much any e-shop from Europe and see how people really write it ;) Not sure why you're trying to mentor an European about usage of Euro symbol. Anyway, I agree that you'd need to deal with a lot of cases if you want to cover 100% of currencies.

Comment: @walther This is all irrelevant. The point is that there ARE evidently cases where it is written 3€50, no matter how rare they are, and these cases should be accounted for..

Comment: @DevNullFin please consider my answer, it's simple and should work with all the edge cases everyone is pointing out, they're over complicating the issue IMO. And don't forget to accept an answer that works best for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you already know how to parse the string into a number type (correct me if I'm wrong). You're using `double` in your example, I would suggest `decimal` but that's your choice.

To get the currency symbol you can use a simple regular expression

```
Regex ex = new Regex(@"\p{Sc}");
CurrencySymbol = ex.Match(input).Value;
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: +1 for using lesser known regex which really helps. The `\p` matches any character in the named character class specified inside `{}` (these are Unicode groups and block ranges), and the `Sm` is the ***Unicode* Currency_Symbol** group. More about Unicode groups at: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: Thanks @Protron I intended to explain this better but I was about to miss the bus.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. It works fine with Currency Symbol like $, €, ¥, £, ₨ fine with all Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this link as well to give you and idea as to the many different ways you can find and or use IndexOf 
[IndexOf String Examples][1]

the question is will the format always have the $ as the first char..? if the answer is yes
regardless of USC or Foreign Currency use the String.IndexOf Method

```
String.IndexOf("$")
```

here is a coded example that you may look at

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // A.
    // The input string.
    const string s = "Tom Cruise is an Idiot he should pay $54.95.";

    // B.
    // Test with IndexOf.
    if (s.IndexOf("$") != -1)
    {
        Console.Write("string contains '$'");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output

string contains '$'

Comment: Your example allows him to identify whether a $ is contained in the string, but what he asked for was how to extract *any* currency symbol from his input string and also the amount..

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try with?

```
float curSymbol;
bool isValid = float.TryParse(curValue, 
    NumberStyles.Currency,
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), out curSymbol);
```

Get the curSymbol. :) Be sure to pass currency values with symbol:)

Comment: The out parameter of the `TryParse` method returns the value, not the currency symbol. Secondly, you shouldn't use `float/double` for storing money values, you should use `decimal` instead.